# Change PC Name (visual)

Tags: windows

Is there any way to visually change the PC name on System>About (on Windows 10)? Not actually change the PC name, just show another name while not being the actual one.

I've tried changing it via sysdm.cpl and registry but that won't work...

Comment: Why do you want your computer to show up as a different name but have the name stay the same?

Comment: @Daniel Vargas: Why not just change the **Computer description** field to what you want? Unless you are trying to trick someone or something?

Comment: I do want to trick someone

Comment: *"I do want to trick someone."*  We are always glad to help community members with their problems.  However, Super User isn't designed to be a source of information to help you prank your friends.  I'm sure that there are people within the Reddit realm who would be glad to help you in that regard.

Comment: I already fixed it why do you still comment

Comment: Because the motivation for your question is inappropriate within the Super User community.  Besides, you didn't actually *"fix"* anything.

Comment: i meant solved,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

The computer's name is...the computer's name.  That's all there is to it.

---

You don't explain *why* you want to do this, but here are some alternate solutions that may be relevant to your request:

- Create an A (or AAAA for IPv6) record in your network's DNS server with an alternate name. You can use the alternate name to communicate with the PC over the network.  (Note that this is a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup> and lots of things won't work properly.)
- Create an alternate name entry in the HOSTS file of another PC. That PC can use the alternate name to connect to the target PC.  Same Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup> problems apply.
- Repeat "My computer name is *[alternate name]*" while using the PC. Because you really don't have any other good options.

Comment: Figured this answer would come so I used a script to change it. Thanks for the help

Comment: I thought you *didn't* want to change the PC name??

Comment: I didn't, but since you stated that there were no workarounds for this, I found a script on github which does the job. I don't even have to restart to change it